# Can't validate against XSD

Tags: php, xml, libxml2, xsd-validation

I have a problem similiar to [No matching global declaration available for the validation root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426154/no-matching-global-declaration-available-for-the-validation-root) but it does not help me in solving my issue with validating XML.
In the comments from php.net I read that the child elements of the root element need a namespace too or something. I tried variations but it would not solve the problem nor change the message yet. Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
libxml Version => 2.7.6
libxml
libxml2 Version => 2.7.6
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.7.6
```

PHP:

```
print_r($xml->schemaValidate('customer.xsd'));
```

Error:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::schemaValidate():
Element '{http://xxx.de/ecom-customer}customerExport':
No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
```

XML beginning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xxx:customerExport xmlns:xxx="http://xxx.de/ecom-customer">
  <datasource>PROD</datasource>
...
```

XSD partial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xxx="http://xxx.de/ecom-customer"
targetNamespace="http://xxx.de/ecom-customer"
jxb:version="2.0">

<xsd:element name="customerExport" type="xxx:customerExport"
    xmlns="xxx">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <jxb:class name="CustomerExportRoot" />
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: You did not define the namespace http://xxx/ecom-customer in the XSD.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, gonna investigate the missing namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema document should specify that you are declaring elements (and other things) for the namespace `http://xxx/ecom-customer`. Use the `targetNamespace` attribute on the root element.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="..."
>

  ...
  <xs:element name="customerExport">...</xs:element>
  ...
</xs:schema>
```

As it is, your schema declares an element whose expanded name is `{}customerExport`, not one whose expanded name is `{http://xxx/ecom-customer}customerExport`.

Comment: I have an updated XSD now containing the `targetNamespace` with the name same as my namespace in XML, I still get the same error.