# Unable to validate XML with schema but works by reading the written file from it

Tags: python, xml, xsd, lxml

I am currently using `lxml` and want to validate a XML content.

I wrote it completely in Python from `tei = etree.Element("TEI", nsmap={None: 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0'}` with many subelements.

At a moment, I want to check if the structure is ok using a specific `.xsd` file using the following code:

```
xmlschema_doc = etree.parse(xsd_file_path)
xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
# run check
status = xmlschema.validate(xml_tree)
```

It returns False with error `Element 'TEI': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.`

I observe a very weird thing that if I write the xml using

```
ET = etree.ElementTree(xmlData)
ET.write('test.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

and if I reopen it with `b= etree.parse('test.xml')` I finally had no error and the xml structure is valid as a result of `xmlschema.validate(b)`

Any idea about what I need to add in my xml structure?

**EDIT:**
First items in the not valid XML [image: linesXML]

First items in the valid XML file [image: linefile]

**EDIT:**

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <text>
    <body>
      <listBibl>
        <biblFull>
          <titleStmt>
            <title xml:lang="en">article</title>
            <title xml:lang="fr">article</title>
            <title type="sub" xml:lang="en">A subtitle</title>
            <author role="aut">
              <persName>
                <forename type="first">John</forename>
                <surname>Doe</surname>
              </persName>
              <email>email</email>
              <idno type="http://orcid.org/">orcid</idno>
              <affiliation ref="#localStruct-affiliation"/>
              <affiliation ref="#struct-affiliation"/>
            </author>
            <author role="aut">
              <persName>
                <forename type="first">Jane</forename>
                <forename type="middle">Middle</forename>
                <surname>Doe</surname>
              </persName>
              <email>email</email>
              <idno type="http://orcid.org/">orcid</idno>
              <affiliation ref="#localStruct-affiliationA"/>
              <affiliation ref="#localStruct-affiliationB"/>
            </author>
          </titleStmt>
          <editionStmt>
            <edition>
              <ref type="file" subtype="author" n="1" target="upload.pdf"/>
            </edition>
          </editionStmt>
          <publicationStmt>
            <availability>
              <licence target="https://creativecommons.org/licenses//cc-by/"/>
            </availability>
          </publicationStmt>
          <notesStmt>
            <note type="audience" n="2"/>
            <note type="invited" n="1"/>
            <note type="popular" n="0"/>
            <note type="peer" n="1"/>
            <note type="proceedings" n="0"/>
            <note type="commentary">small comment</note>
            <note type="description">small description</note>
          </notesStmt>
          <sourceDesc>
            <biblStruct>
              <analytic>
                <title xml:lang="en">article</title>
                <title xml:lang="fr">article</title>
                <title type="sub" xml:lang="en">A subtitle</title>
                <author role="aut">
                  <persName>
                    <forename type="first">John</forename>
                    <surname>Doe</surname>
                  </persName>
                  <email>email</email>
                  <idno type="http://orcid.org/">orcid</idno>
                  <affiliation ref="#localStruct-affiliation"/>
                  <affiliation ref="#struct-affiliation"/>
                </author>
                <author role="aut">
                  <persName>
                    <forename type="first">Jane</forename>
                    <forename type="middle">Middle</forename>
                    <surname>Doe</surname>
                  </persName>
                  <email>email</email>
                  <idno type="http://orcid.org/">orcid</idno>
                  <affiliation ref="#localStruct-affiliationA"/>
                  <affiliation ref="#localStruct-affiliationB"/>
                </author>
              </analytic>
              <monogr>
                <idno type="isbn">978-1725183483</idno>
                <idno type="halJournalId">117751</idno>
                <idno type="issn">xxx</idno>
                <imprint>
                  <publisher>springer</publisher>
                  <biblScope unit="serie">a special collection</biblScope>
                  <biblScope unit="volume">20</biblScope>
                  <biblScope unit="issue">1</biblScope>
                  <biblScope unit="pp">10-25</biblScope>
                  <date type="datePub">2024-01-01</date>
                </imprint>
              </monogr>
              <series/>
              <idno type="doi">reg</idno>
              <idno type="arxiv">ger</idno>
              <idno type="bibcode">erg</idno>
              <idno type="ird">greger</idno>
              <idno type="pubmed">greger</idno>
              <idno type="ads">gaergezg</idno>
              <idno type="pubmedcentral">gegzefdv</idno>
              <idno type="irstea">vvxc</idno>
              <idno type="sciencespo">gderg</idno>
              <idno type="oatao">gev</idno>
              <idno type="ensam">xcvcxv</idno>
              <idno type="prodinra">vxcv</idno>
              <ref type="publisher">https://publisher.com/ID</ref>
              <ref type="seeAlso">https://link1.com/ID</ref>
              <ref type="seeAlso">https://link2.com/ID</ref>
              <ref type="seeAlso">https://link3.com/ID</ref>
            </biblStruct>
          </sourceDesc>
          <profileDesc>
            <textClass>
              <keywords scheme="author">
                <term xml:lang="en">keyword1</term>
                <term xml:lang="en">keyword2</term>
                <term xml:lang="fr">mot-clé1</term>
                <term xml:lang="fr">mot-clé2</term>
              </keywords>
              <classCode scheme="halDomain" n="physics"/>
              <classCode scheme="halDomain" n="halDomain2"/>
              <classCode scheme="halTypology" n="ART"/>
            </textClass>
          </profileDesc>
        </biblFull>
      </listBibl>
    </body>
    <back>
      <listOrg type="structures">
        <org type="institution" xml:id="localStruct-affiliation">
          <orgName>laboratory for MC, university of Yeah</orgName>
          <orgName type="acronym">LMC</orgName>
          <desc>
            <address>
              <addrLine>Blue street 155, 552501 Olso, Norway</addrLine>
              <country key="LS">Lesotho</country>
            </address>
            <ref type="url" target="https://lmc.univ-yeah.com"/>
          </desc>
        </org>
        <org type="institution" xml:id="localStruct-affiliationB">
          <orgName>laboratory for MCL, university of Yeah</orgName>
          <orgName type="acronym">LMCL</orgName>
          <desc>
            <address>
              <addrLine>Blue street 155, 552501 Olso, Norway</addrLine>
              <country key="NO">Norway</country>
            </address>
            <ref type="url" target="https://lmcl.univ-yeah.com"/>
          </desc>
        </org>
      </listOrg>
    </back>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Comment: XSD 1.1 for Python.
The xmlschema library is an implementation of XML Schema for Python (supports Python 3.7+).
https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/

Comment: If you use `status = xmlschema.validate(xml_tree.getroottree())` or perhaps `status = xmlschema.validate(tei.getroottree())` instead of `status = xmlschema.validate(xml_tree)`, does the instance document validate against the schema?

Comment: The XML structure is different from the schema.  The structure check is the opening and closing tags are properly matched.  The schema check the contents of the xml values to see if they are correct as well as all the tags are valid.  You error indicates the TEI tag is not consistent with the schema.  Schema is not automatically checked when reading an XML.  So reading is working but schema check is failing.

Comment: Check also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426185/12621346) maybe similar issue?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky same behavior with xmlschema: only the parsed content from a XML file is valid

Comment: @MartinHonnen the use of `getrottree` changes nothing

Comment: `xmlschema` provides error message :`Reason: Unexpected child with tag 'text' at position 1. Tag 'ns1:text' expected.`

Comment: Consider to show a minimal but complete example of the Python code creating the XML, of the schema. I suspect it is a namespace issue. Do you create both the root element as well as all descendant elements in the TEI namespace?

Comment: @jdweng I edited my original post. I use for the test exactly the same method using `.validate` of `lxml`. I only have the error with my initial XML tree but not by reading the file written from it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen the XSD fil is here: `https://hal.science/documents/aofr.xsd` for the Python code, it is more complicated... but it is weird to not have any error about namespace by reading the xml file...

Comment: the not valid XML tree starts with the line provided in the original post

Comment: In addition `xmlschema.is_valid(xml_tree.getroottree())` returns False and `xmlschema.is_valid(etree.tostring(xml_tree.getroottree()))` returns True...

Comment: Same behavior with lmxl: `xmlschema.validate(xml_tree)` return False and `xmlschema.validate(etree.parse(BytesIO(etree.tostring(xml_tree))))` returns True

Comment: Have you checked the encoding, too? You can open with Notepad++ for example and check if the encoding is really utf-8. Your snap shot pictures, doesn’t help if we don’t have the dummy files., what shows the problem.

Comment: `file test.xml` returns `test.xml: XML 1.0 document text, Unicode text, UTF-8 text`

Comment: I finally uploaded the whole XML file

Comment: Please show the code creating the subelements.

Comment: ```tei = etree.Element("TEI", nsmap=dflt.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE_XML)
    Logger.debug('Add first elements')
    text = etree.SubElement(tei, 'text')
    body = etree.SubElement(text, 'body')
    listBibl = etree.SubElement(body, 'listBibl')
    biblFull = etree.SubElement(listBibl, 'biblFull')
    Logger.debug('Start to add metadata')
    Logger.debug('Add title(s) 1/2')
    titleStmt = etree.SubElement(biblFull, 'titleStmt')```

Comment: with `dflt.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE_XML = {None: 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0'}`

Comment: Against which [.xsd](https://tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/xsd/) have you done the validation?

Comment: @Hermann12 this one: https://hal.science/documents/aofr.xsd

Comment: This schma throu an error about this line <script id="__gaOptOutExtension"/> maybe this is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces, you should basically use

```
TEI_NAMESPACE = "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
TEI = "{%s}" % TEI_NAMESPACE

NSMAP = {None : TEI_NAMESPACE} # the default namespace (no prefix)

root = etree.Element(TEI + "TEI", nsmap=NSMAP) # lxml only!
text = etree.SubElement(root, TEI + "text")
```

and so on for all elements, to ensure they are created in the TEI namespace.

A minimal in memory created ElementTree to be valid against the schema (after I downloaded it together with the imported W3C xml.xsd) is e.g.

```
from lxml import etree

TEI_NAMESPACE = "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
TEI = "{%s}" % TEI_NAMESPACE

NSMAP = {None : TEI_NAMESPACE} # the default namespace (no prefix)

root = etree.Element(TEI + "TEI", nsmap=NSMAP) # lxml only!
text = etree.SubElement(root, TEI + "text")
body = etree.SubElement(text, TEI + "body")
listBibl = etree.SubElement(body, TEI + "listBibl")
biblFull = etree.SubElement(listBibl, TEI + "biblFull")
sourceDesc = etree.SubElement(biblFull, TEI + "sourceDesc")
profileDesc = etree.SubElement(biblFull, TEI + "profileDesc")


xmlschema_doc = etree.parse("aofr.xsd")
xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
# run check
status = xmlschema.validate(root)

print(status)

print(xmlschema.error_log)
```

Comment: It is the write way to correct my issue. lxml seems to assume that the namespace was not applied on every element but apply it when it write the file...